# What are possible outputs of this dart code

Tags: dart

Consider the following Dart code:

```
main() {
  
  var myFuture = Future(
      (){
        print("Executing Future"); 
        return 10;
      }
  );
  print("Exiting main now");
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
Exiting main now
Executing Future
```

My understanding of Dart code execution is that the app executes in an isolate with a single thread (called an event loop). This event loop processes events sequentially as they arrive. The creation of the Future in the above code just puts a new event into the event pipeline, which the event loop picks up for processing after it is done processing the current event (which is the execution of main).

This means that there is absolutely no possibility that the order of the lines in the output would be reversed. I mean, it is guaranteed 100% that the above program will NEVER print this:

```
Executing Future
Exiting main now
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, in general, not write code like this where you are dependent on the order which async events are being executed. If you are depending on something to happen, you should await the dependent futures to get values.

The reason is that your code does execute in the order you describes. But we could also have made a `Future.sync` which changes how the same program is executed (not really surprising based on the name of that constructor):

```dart
void main() {
  final myFuture = Future.sync(() {
    print("Executing Future");
    return 10;
  });
  print("Exiting main now");
}

// Returns:
// Executing Future
// Exiting main now
```

You cannot really see how much code is being executed before a `Future` is returned to your calling code. Which is a major reason why you should never depend of execution order when it comes to asynchronously code besides awaiting on needed futures/streams to get a value.

But yeah, if this is just a theoretical question, you are right about how things works and your specific code would always be executed like you are saying based on the API description of the `Future` constructor:

> Creates a future containing the result of calling computation asynchronously with Timer.run.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-async/Future/Future.html

I can in general recommend the following article about the event loops in Dart:

https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a

**UPDATE 1**

The reason why I am saying:

> You cannot really see how much code is being executed before a `Future` is returned to your calling code.

Is because we can do something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  print('Step 1');
  myAsyncMethod().then(print);
  print('Step 3');
}

Future<String> myAsyncMethod() async {
  print('Step 2');
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), () => null);
  return 'Step 4';
}
```

Which will output:

```
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
Step 4
```

The reason for this behavior is because `async` methods will run as a sync method until the first `await` operation where it will then afterwards behave like an async function. So when we call `myAsyncMethod` we are right away executing `print('Step 2')` but then we go back and executes `print('Step 3')`.

So if we just look at:

```dart
myAsyncMethod().then(print);
```

We don't really know what have been executed before we got the `Future`. It should also be noted that this is not unique to `async` marked method. We could also have done the following which returns the same output:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  print('Step 1');
  myAsyncMethod().then(print);
  print('Step 3');
}

Future<String> myAsyncMethod() {
  final completer = Completer<String>();
  print('Step 2');
  Future.delayed(
    const Duration(milliseconds: 1),
    () => completer.complete('Step 4'),
  );
  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is a theoretical question. But I don't agree with your comment about not depending on the order. Dart guarantees that the code in an isolate is executed by a single thread called the event loop, right? So, the above order is guaranteed. Correct? If it is guaranteed then it is dependable even though there is not much use of it.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by, "you cannot really see how much code is being executed before a Future is returned to your calling code?" Every line of code in main will be executed before the Future is completed. That's the direct implication of the fact that there is only one thread (the event loop) that executes all code. So, if it is currently executing the code in main, it cannot complete the Future. Right? Only after the code in main ends, it will get to executing the code in Future.

Comment: @Priyshrm I have added an "Update 1" section to my answer where I try to explain my "you cannot really see how much code is being executed before a Future is returned to your calling code?" comment. I hope the added explanation helps on understanding that part better.

Comment: ok, I see, yes that is a very tricky code that you have shown (your first example). That is really messed up. I expected Step 4 to be printed before Step 3. 
It will take me some time to understand your second example.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Priyshrm A `Completer` is a way to generate a `Future` we can return right away and later fill it with a value. `Future` in Dart really just means a variable which might get a value in the future and you are able to subscibe to that event. So what I do in the second example is spawn a `Timer` (done behind `Future.delayed`) which is being executed later and calls `completer.complete`. That gives our `Future` a value which adds an event on the even queue for our subscriber of that future to be executed as our next event.

Comment: You can read more about it here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-async/Completer-class.html